# API url routing - Django/Postman

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework

I am messing around with a backend Django API tutorial (Django 2.1) and I am having trouble pulling 'profile' information via Postman. My assumption is that I am not correctly stating my url in my urls.py.

Here is my project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('conduit.apps.authentication.urls'), name='authentication'),
    path('api/v1/', include('conduit.apps.profiles.urls'), name='profiles')
]
```

Here is my profiles.urls.py:

```
from .views import ProfileRetrieveAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    path('profiles/<username:username>/', ProfileRetrieveAPIView.as_view())
]
```

I think my issue has to do with how I am implementing / to the end of my path. My only other relevant experience with this kind of mechanism was on prior projects where I was using something like this for unique blog post url routing (which I have done successfully):

```
".../<slug:slug>/"
```

Now, here is my relevant class-based view for the above url:

```
class ProfileRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
renderer_classes = (ProfileJSONRenderer,)
serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

def retrieve(self, request, username, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.select_related('user').get(
            user__username=username
        )
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        raise ProfileDoesNotExist

    serializer = self.serializer_class(profile)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

You can see in my retrieve function, I am working with a username attribute. This is what I think I am trying to match up with my url path. I am guessing that I am probably not understanding how to correctly associate the url path variable (that terminology doesn't sound right) with my view. Thanks!

Also - the tutorial I am following is having me make a GET request in postman. The collection I downloaded as part of the tutorial has the following url in populated by default:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/profiles/celeb_harry
```

Where is the 'celeb_' prefacing my username ('harry') coming from. I am not seeing that in any of my .py files (renderers, serializers, views, urls, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `lookup_field` in you View. For example:

```
class ProfileRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'username'

 path('profiles/<username>/', ProfileRetrieveAPIView.as_view())
```

What happens is that, inside `get_object` method of the view, based on `lookup_field`, a `get_object_or_404` is executed. Please see the implementation in [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L88) for understanding how **RetrieveAPIView** works.

Comment: No luck with adding that lookup field. I am seeing the following error now when I attempt to make a GET request via Postman:

 'ImproperlyConfigured: URL route 'profiles/<username:username>/' uses invalid converter 'username'. 

is 'username' a reserved keyword?

Comment: do I need to redefine the get_object function and return a new obj altogether instead of just setting the lookup_field variable?

Comment: there is no converter named `username`, so `<username:username>` will not work. So either use `<username>` or `<str:username>`

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry about that, I thought I did.